# Display zero height bar in chart

Tags: website-design, charts

We have a web application displaying some values on a bar chart (values shown are difference values: our product's performance vs all other products' performance).

Time to time value to be displayed is 0, which case no bar is shown and therefore it looks like missing data.

What's the best practice to indicate value is 0, not missing?

[image]

Comment: A thin line / border would be my preference. (Could also be applied to the top/bottom of the other bars, a slightly darker shade than the red or green of the rest of the bar.)

Answer (score 1):

You can try being clear with a label.

If users are accustomed to at-a-glance determinations of activity, you could just provide a subtle label along the Y axis:

[image]

If you go this route, you also might need to distinguish between *no activity* vs. *missing data*

Either way, you can test to see if this is clear enough for your user base.

Comment: "you also might need to distinguish between no activity vs. missing data" - "no activity" is not an option. 0 means "no difference" and it's a completely valid result, like any other number. Why I should display this information as text while all other values are displayed as bar?

Answer (score 0):

I think a horizontal line at the point should suffice, are there x-axis labels that would help the user know there is a data point there?